# Export data from Adwords, Facebook ads, etc

Tags: php, facebook, google-ads-api, bing-api

I am making a basic internal dashboard to keep track of some key metrics at a new startup I'm working on.  One of the things I'd like include is advertising spend on a few different ad platforms (Google Adwords, Google display, Facebook, Bing, etc).

I know most (maybe all) of them have API's, but if I could avoid writing a custom piece of code for each one that would be great.  Is there any way to get this data using a third party service or generic library?  I haven't been able to find anything, but I'm hoping something is available.

Answer (score 0):

These are all very different APIs that solve different problems and have different data. You are going to have to write custom code for each API.